# Another Lebesgue measure question

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a Lebesgue measure on the Borel $\sigma$ algebra.

Then is $\mu( [0,\frac{1}{4}) \bigcup [\frac{3}{4},1])$ 
just $\mu([\frac{3}{4},1]) + \mu([\frac{3}{4},1])$

with 
$\mu( [0,\frac{1}{4})) = \frac{1}{4} - 0 = \frac{1}{4}$

and $\mu([\frac{3}{4},1]) = 1 - \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Yes, since the sets are disjoint

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct, since the two intervals $[0, 1/4)$ and $[3/4, 1]$ are disjoint and $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ for any disjoint measurable sets $A, B$ and measures $\mu$.